# How to avoid a duplicate username in csv file, and display an error if duplicate exist with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to insert a csv file to MySQL database, but I have a problem with duplicate username.
if inside a csv file there is two identical username it takes the last one and ignore the first one.
So, I want to display an error for users.
**How I can read and verify the duplicate name in csv file before inserting to database ?**
here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['importCSV'])) {
   // Allowed mime types
   $csvMimes = array(
      'text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.msexcel',
      'text/csv', 'applicaton/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'
   );

   // validate whether selected file is csv file
   if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'] && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes))) {
      // if the file is uploaded
      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

         // Open uploaded file withe only-read mode
         $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

// ** How to check if there is duplicate name in CSV ? **
         // skipe the first line
         fgetcsv($csvFile);

         while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1024, ';')) !== FALSE) {
            // Get each row data
            $username = $line[0];
            $email    = $line[1];
            $country  = $line[2];
            $type     = $line[3];
            $password = $line[4];
            
            // Chack whether prospect already exists in the database with the same email
            $prevQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID FROM var WHERE email = :email");
            $prevQuery->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $prevQuery->execute();

            if ($prevQuery->rowCount() > 0) {
               $updateStmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE var SET username = :username,
                                                            country = :country,
                                                            role = :role,
                                                            password = :password,
                                                         WHERE   
                                                            email = :email
                                             ");

               $updateStmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
               $updateStmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
               $updateStmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
               $updateStmt->bindParam(':role', $type);
               $updateStmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

               // $updateStmt->bindParam(':name', $name); 
               $updateStmt->execute();
            } else {
               $insertStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO var (username, email, country, role, password)                                             
                                                         VALUES(:username, :email, :country, :role, :password);                    
                                             ");

               $insertStmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
               $insertStmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
               $insertStmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
               $insertStmt->bindParam(':role', $type);
               $insertStmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
               
               $insertStmt->execute();
            }
         }
         fclose($csvFile);
         $qMsg = '?status=succ';
      } else {
         $qMsg = '?status=err';
      }
   } else {
      $qMsg = '?status=invalide_file';
   }
}
header('location: index.php' . $qMsg);
?>
<!---
Dispaly the error message here 
-->
<p class='alert alert-danger text-center'> User can not be inserted because of dublicate username. </p>
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="input-group import-csv mb-2 pt-1 pb-1">
         <input type="file" class="form-control " name="file" />
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="importCSV" value="Upload" />
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Put a UNIQUE INDEX on the username column in your database, and then handle the _error_ that will result from trying to insert a new record with a duplicate value for that column.

Comment: it's. when I add a user by form it gets error. but when I insert many users by a csv file. it takes only one of them (the last one or first one)

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array to store the already fetched usernames and check every value against it, like this:

```
$usernames = Array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1024, ';')) !== FALSE) {
    if (isset($usernames[$line[0]])) {
        print("Duplicate username $line[0]");
        break; //Or do not break if you want to list every duplicate at once
    }
    $usernames[$line[0]] = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it takes the first user this time and ignore the second one

Comment: This was what you wanted. The first username is valid, since it's the first occurence, then when the program find another one, it gives you an error.

Comment: but it insert anyway inside the database. I put it as bellow ` while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1024, ';')) !== FALSE) { if (isset($usernames[$line[0]])) { print("Duplicate username $line[0]"); break; } $usernames[$line[0]] = true; // Get each row data $username = $line[0]; $email = $line[1]; $country = $line[2]; $type = $line[3]; $password = $line[4]; ` mybe i put the code as wrong way

Comment: Maybe you should put my code before doing anything else. The "normal" way of doing things like this: 1. Validate every data, report errors, and stop executing. 2. If everything is valid, do the DB stuff. 3. If needed, commit what you have done. 4. Inform the user that everything was fine.